# JAVA Flower counter program

Tags: java

I have to write a program that uses 2 arrays. The first array stores 5 flower names, and the 2nd stores the price of each flower.

The user will input what kind of flower and how many and the program will output the cost. I'm having trouble outputting the associated cost of the particular flower with the particular cost.

I want to use 5 if statements, but am having trouble with the flowers strings. Any suggestions?

Here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FlowerCounter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String[] flowers = new String[5];
        double[] price = {.50, .75, 1.50, .50, .80};

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What kind of flower would you " +
            "like to purchase? \nPetunia, Pansy, Rose," +
            " Violet, or Carnation?");

        String index = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How many " + index +"s" + " would you like?");
        int count = keyboard.nextInt();

        double total = count * price.length;
        System.out.println("The cost for " + count  +  index  + " is " + total);             
    }        
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? Because a Map<String,Double> would work much better in practice.

Comment: @EthanSteinberg Yeah I'm pretty sure this is homework..

Comment: Yes it is homework. I am not familiar with Map. I've only been studying java for 9 weeks now LOL.

Comment: @EthanSteinberg, practice object of Flower would be expected ;-). But for this app an enum is my best choice ;-).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Gonna google your suggestion cause my textbook isn't that great.

Comment: I can't use enum because it must be an array.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FlowerCounter {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   String[] flowers = {"Petunia", "Pansy", "Rose", "Violet", "Carnation"};
   double[] price = {.50, .75, 1.50, .50, .80};
   double cost = 0;

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("What kind of flower would you " +
                          "like to purchase? \nPetunia, Pansy, Rose," +
                          " Violet, or Carnation?");

   String index = keyboard.nextLine();

   System.out.println("How many " + index +"s" + " would you like?");
   int count = keyboard.nextInt();

  if (index.equals("Petunia") || index.equals("petunia"))
       cost = (double)price[0] * count;
   else if (index.equals("Pansy") || index.equals("pansy"))
       cost = (double)price[1] * count;
   else if (index.equals("Rose") || index.equals("rose"))
       cost = (double)price[2] * count;
   else if (index.equals("Violet") || index.equals("violet"))
       cost = (double)price[3] * count;
   else if (index.equals("Carnation") || index.equals("carnation"))
       cost = (double)price[4] * count;
   else 
       System.out.println("wrong flower");

   System.out.println("The cost for " + count+ " "  +  index  + " is " + cost);            
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand that people don't like to give the answer to us students, but your answer will be studied. I really want to learn java and this will not just be turned in and forgotten about! Thanks again

Comment: It's usually not customary to just give code on homework questions, and using a boolean OR instead of `equalsIgnoreCase` baffles me to no end.

Comment: This is homework, so don't do it for him, he must learn with this. Just explain him what he is doing wrong and point him to the right direction. In your solution all those if-else's are a bad idea, you should do a for or while cycle to find the index of the flower. For just 5 flowers what you did is fine, but imagine you must add more? Many more? You could use 'index.equalsIgnoreCase()' so the flower names are not case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way you put values into the price array, you will have to place the flowers in that order.

Iterate through the names of the flowers, and when you find the specific index of the flower that matches what was input (remember:  `.equals()` and not `==`), return the price of that flower through the use of that index.

Answer (score 0):

I would think something like a `Map<String, Double> flowers = new HashMap<String, Double>();`, and then could quite easily check with `flowers.get(index)` to get it's value.

Also might be worthwhile to check to make sure they've input a valid flower name.

[Documentation for HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

[The Map page in the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

Comment: You're right about the maps, but the assignment calls for two arrays.  We can't violate that constraint.

Comment: Aah I guess I wasn't paying close enough attention to the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to initialize your `flowers` array with the names of the flowers.

You could do this manually for each one(e.g. `flowers[0] = "Petunia";`), or you could do it as you did the price array in one step(e.g. `String[] flowers = {"Petunia", "Pansy","Rose","Violet","Carnation"};`).

Then you would need to find which index of the flowers array contains the flower name input by the user. Cycle through each index of the flowers array until one matches(make sure to use `index.equals(flowers[testIndex])`, not the `==` operator).

Finally multiply the count by price at the index of the inputted flower name to get the total cost.

Answer (score 0):

You are just using the indexes, but not the arrays.

To access the flower names you must use the array flower like this:

```
flower[index]
```

And to access the prices:

```
price[index]
```

with 'index' being a int and not a String. If you must find the index (position) of the a given flower, you must iterate all the array until you find it.

You probably may want to use a map instead of 2 arrays:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

With a map you can access the flower price using the flower name as the key.
Just declare a `Map<String, Double> prices = new HashMap<String, Double>();`